# Specify expression in LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can specify expression in LIKE operator

I want to select all row in table where column Name starts with a-zA-Z followed by # and does not have two dots together (..)

i tries this WHERE NAME LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]*#*'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE name LIKE '[a-zA-Z]#%' AND NOT (name LIKE '%..%')`

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE Name LIKE '[A-Za-z]#%'
    AND Name NOT LIKE '%..%'
```